# keep getting "not a statement" when I try to compile for Java

Tags: java

I'm taking a Pre-AP Comp Sci class and figured I join the club and when doing some practice problems online, I stumbled on this question:

> Write a program that will print out every number within the range 500 to 1000 that is divisible by 7.  You will need to use mod (`%`) for this problem."

I was able to get all other similar problems solved with little or no issue but this one I can't seem to get. I'm thinking the issue would would be in my for loop at the `x % 7` part. 
Here's what I've gotten as far as code:

```
class javaRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int x = 500; x <= 1000; x % 7) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: What is your problem? What doesn't work?

Comment: FYI, Java classes should start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general form of the for statement can be expressed as follows:

```
for (initialization; termination; increment/decrement) {
    statement(s)
}
```

x%7 doesn't make any change on x. Correct way to do this would be,

```
for(int x=500; x<=1000; x++)
{
    if(x%7==0)
        System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try the following

```
for(int x = 500; x <= 1000; x++)
{
    if (x%7 == 0){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct when you say the problem is with your For loop.

You should probably use something like this

```
class javaRunner 
{        
    public static void main(String[] args)  
     {     
       for(int x = 500; x <= 1000; x++)     //For loop to go through all numbers from 500 to 1000
        {         
          if(x%7 == 0) //Will go into this loop only if x is divisible by 7
          {
              System.out.println(x); 
          }    
        }  
     } 
}
```